# How does one say 'tried as an adult' in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, words

My best guess would be 「成人・成年として裁判にかける」, but neither seems to return many results. Incidentally, what's the minimum age to be tried as an adult in Japan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

> 成人として[裁]{さば}く -- to try as an adult (active)
>   成人として裁かれる -- to be tried as an adult (passive)

---

I think the minimum age to be tried as an adult is 14 years old...

[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/少年法#.E6.A6.82.E8.A6.81](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B0%91%E5%B9%B4%E6%B3%95#.E6.A6.82.E8.A6.81)

Comment: Thank you! But I would imagine it's hardly usual for 14-year-olds to be tried as adults. What's the age where you can only be tried as an adult, would perhaps be a better question.

Comment: んー、未成年が民事裁判で責任を問われることはないので、わざわざ’成人として’をつけなくても、(刑事で)裁きを受けること自体が被告が成人しているか、逆送致されたことを示せると思ったんですが。質問の意味を受ければ、「逆送致される」が実質的な日本語に当たるとは思います。

Comment: "to be tried as an adult"は、「裁きを受ける」または「逆送致される」と和訳するのがいい、ということでしょうか。"What's the minimum age to be tried as an adult in Japan?" は、「成人として裁かれるのは、日本では何歳以上ですか？」ではなく「裁きを受けるのは、日本では何歳以上ですか？」とか「逆送致されるのは、日本では何歳以上ですか？」と和訳する方がいいと思われますか？

Comment: 「裁きを受ける」とか「裁かれる」の訳自体があまり良くないと思います。tried as an adult という表現は、民事裁判ではなく刑事裁判なのは明らかなので「裁き」という訳は意味が広すぎると思います。

Comment: あの…上のコメントで言ったのは、あなたが仰るように"to be tried as an adult"を「裁きを受ける」とか「逆送致される」と訳して、"What's the minimum age to be tried as an adult in Japan?" を（「成人として」をつけないで」）「裁きを受けるのは、日本では何歳以上ですか？」とか「逆送‌​致されるのは、日本では何歳以上ですか？」‌​と訳したら、意味が分からないでしょう？ってことだったんですけど…。

Answer (score 2):

We just say (刑事)裁判にかける if the suspect is an adult who is over twenty.

As opposed to adults, juvenile suspects who are between age of nineteen and roughly twelve will take 少年審判 at 家庭裁判所
(Family court) first, 
where the judge decide what punishment will  be conducive to suspects’ reformation.

[image: 少年審判の配置]

As the image shows, there is no prosecutor at 少年審判 so the suspects won’t be ‘tried as 
an adult’ unless the judge decides to remand them. 
According to the juvenile law, suspects under 13 shall not be prosecuted.

The press often use 家裁送致する(される) for the juvenile suspects and 児童相談所に通告 for pupils.

Answer (score 0):

成人の法廷で裁かれる

As for your second question this article may be interesting: https://www.japantimes.co.jp/opinion/2015/05/28/editorials/juvenile-crime-and-punishment/#.WiymVGJcWEc